# Сгрупировать по полю, а вывести связанное с ним

Tags: sql, sql-server

Реальная ситуация побольше, но я смоделирую ее так.
Есть таблицы Name(ID, Name) и Cost(ID, Cost). Нужно связать их по полю ID и вывести суму товаров, но выводить нужно не ID а Name. Нужно что то типа такого только рабочее)

```
select Name.Name, SUM(Cost.Cost) from Name join Cost 
    on Name.ID = Cost.ID
group by Name.ID
```

---

Если взять реальное задание, то есть таблици TOV, DMZ, DMS

[image]

Нужно вывести `TOV.NTOV`, `SUM(DMS.KOL)`, `SUM(DMS.CENA * DMS.KOL)` (связав таблицы по полям `TOV.KTOV = DMS.KTOV` и `DMZ.NDM = DMS.NDM`) по заданной дате (например '20140501') и по `DMZ_.PR = 2`, группируя по `TOV.KTOV`.

Пояснения: TOV - товары (идентификатор, название, тип), DMZ - документы (дата, номер, тип(приход, уход)), DMS - поставки (какой товар, по какому документу, количество, цена, тип(знаю что не нужно дублировать, но так поставлено задание))

Comment: так как для одного KTOV у вас гарантированно только один NTOV, то просто добавьте NTOV в `group by` это не повлияет на результат. Хотя конечно будут странно выглядеть две строки 'пиво' с какими то данными, относящимися к разным KTOV. но у вас так криво сформулировано задание, тут ничего другого не сделаешь

Comment: Вы просто оба поля через запятую в `group by` укажите и получите 3 строки из которых 2 будут 'пиво'. или вы ожидаете получить какой то другой результат ? Если так, укажите какой конкретно результат вы хотите увидеть на основе показанных данных. И никогда не показывайте входные данные в виде картинки. По тексту хоть можно быстро создать тестовую БД, а по картинке надо руками создавать таблицы и заполнять их.

Comment: если через запятую указать получается 2 строки

Comment: этого не может быть. приведите пример на sqlfiddle.com который дает две строки при группировке по `group by KTOV, NTOV`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Я проверял просто на плохих данных где ответы совпадали.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны группировать по тому полю, к кому используйте агрегирующую функцию, поэтому в вашем случае просто нужна группировка по `Name.Name`:

```
select n.Name, t.cost_sum
from
   (select Name.ID, SUM(Cost.Cost) as cost_sum
    from Name join Cost on Name.ID = Cost.ID
    group by Name.ID) t 
  join Name n ON t.id = n.id
```

Comment: Вот именно что мне то нужно групировать по ID

Comment: @Rusl зачем группировать по ID, если в ответе в итоге Name.Name? Покажите пример данных таблицы, чтобы понимать, зачем вам это надо.

Comment: так поставлено задание

Comment: @Rusl обновил ответ

Comment: ах да, еще проблема в том что нельзя использовать подзапросы

Comment: @Rusl мы обсуждали этот момент в вашем прошлом вопросе на такую же тему, где вы сами не могли понять, что от вас хотел преподаватель. Сейчас, видимо, ситуация у вас снова повторяется. У вас 2 выхода - подзапрос, либо группировка по `group by Name.Name`.

Comment: Странно, так как задание поставлено именно так. Более того я уже делал так как вы говорите, но мне указали на то что я не следую постановке задания.

Answer (score 0):

```
select TOV.NTOV, SUM(DMS.KOL), SUM(DMS.CENA * DMS.KOL) DMS left join TOV on TOV.KTOV = DMS.KTOV  
group by TOV.NTOV  // выберет суммы  

select * from DMZ where DDM = &DataParameter  // выберет документы по дате
```

Остается соединить два запроса

```
select DMS.NDM, TOV.NTOV, SUM(DMS.KOL), SUM(DMS.CENA * DMS.KOL) from DMS  
left join TOV on TOV.KTOV = DMS.KTOV  
left join DMZ on DMZ.NDM = DMS.NDM AND DMZ.DDM = &DataParameter
group by DMS.NDM, TOV.NTOV
```